# Trying to sync live data to a backup server

Tags: 12.04, backup, mysql, rsync

I'd like to take the data from the live system to a backup system (to test new features etc)

Piecing together an rsync command, I have the following.  How do I ensure everything is copied?  Things like an active forum, mysql databases etc.

```
# rsync -aAXv --exclude={"/dev/*","/proc/*","/sys/*","/tmp/*","/media/*","/lost+found","/mnt/backup"} -e 'ssh -p 22' /* root@remote_server.com:/*
```

Comment: Nice question bro , but you can use du <space> folder name to see & compare data on bothsides

Comment: what would the du command arguments be?  would i be able to have it compare both "directories" (/root) on both machines at the same time and with the same output listing?

Comment: You can see on both ends. if you use ssh yes it can be done

Answer (score 1):

For your MySQL databases, you must first dump the data using mysqldump, transfer the dump and then insert it into the backup system (mysql << my_dump)
Alternatively, you could use replication (see: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/replication.html) but I guess it would be overkill in your case.